# Correct default development blockchain port for truffle

Tags: truffle, ethereumjs, ethereumj

How is the truffle port set when one runs `truffle unbox react` and then `truffle develop` ?

The documentation states that the default port is 9545 (https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/using-truffle-develop-and-the-console.html), but the port specified in the downloaded  truffle-config.js is 8545, which
is supposed to be the default port when Ganache is the client.

I also noticed that the default port specified here :

https://github.com/truffle-box/react-box/blob/master/client/src/getWeb3.js

is 8545:

https://github.com/truffle-box/react-box/blob/c33a70f57559c0040f7109f9db498a0f83187776/client/src/getWeb3.js#L26

```
 // Fallback to localhost; use dev console port by default...
      else {
         const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
          "http://127.0.0.1:8545"
      );
```

Can someone help shed light on this ?

Answer (score 1):

`truffle develop` spins up a specially configured ganache to interact with the truffle console. This is on purpose run on a different port (9545) to not conflict with the default ganache port 8545, see https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli-archive).

Comment: Thx, I didn't know it ran ganache internally. Do you know why when I run truffle develop it states : `Truffle Develop started at http://127.0.0.1:8545/`
instead of : `Truffle Develop started at http://127.0.0.1:9545/` ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the way I got it to start up on port 9545 was to modify the truffle-config.js. The default file generated when I ran `truffle unbox react` had these lines:

```
 networks: {
   develop: {
     port: 8545
  }
 }
```

Contrary to the documentation, it does seem like `truffle develop` results in this file being read.

I changed the network name to development:

```
 networks: {
   development: {
     port: 8545
  }
 }
```

And now when I run truffle develop it starts up on port 9545.

`Truffle Develop started at http://127.0.0.1:9545/`

It looks like the Truffle documentation may be a bit outdated.